# cleanest way to restart jboss using a script

Tags: linux, jboss, jboss7.x, ubuntu-12.04

I am using " ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml " to start JBOSS. What is the cleanest way to restart jboss in this case? Any scripts that you can share?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to use CLI console. To restart, type

```
bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:reload
```

To shutdown, type

```
bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:shutdown
```

[Source](https://community.jboss.org/thread/165815?_sscc=t)

Comment: You can also use `bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=":reload"` if you just want to restart the server.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins does the "reload" wait for the pending transactions to finish before reloading?

Comment: My guess would be yes, but to be honest I'm not sure.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I tried ":reload" but I get: 
Communication error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed

Comment: I've seen that from time to time and I think it's a known issue that looks like it's fixed upstream. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1833

Answer (score 31):

[@Petr Mensik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039952/petr-mensik)'s solution works well if you need to shutdown the server. But if you need to restart it in a single operation you can use:

```
jboss-cli.sh -c ":shutdown(restart=true)"
```

Thanks to these [excellent JBoss notes](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2012/08/my-jboss-as7-notes.html).